# How do we select the output of stored procedure into a variable?

Tags: sql-server

I am using EXEC to execute the stored procedure in SQL Server 2008, which is returning the row in that I need to select one varchar value to a variable.

Comment: If you need to get a scalar value back rewrite the procedure to use an [Output parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Can you add some more detail? First try using `INSERT <Table> EXEC <YourSP>` and post back with any issues, clearly explained with sample data and sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use table variable to hold the data returned by the procedure and query the table variable to get the desired varchar value. This way.

```
DECLARE @ResultTable table(ResultValue1 varchar(50))
DECLARE @ResultValue1 varchar(50)

DECLARE @ProcedureName varchar(500)
SET @ProcedureName='USP_TEST1'

INSERT INTO @ResultTable EXECUTE  @ProcedureName;

SET @ResultValue1=(SELECT ResultValue1 FROM @ResultTable)

PRINT @ResultValue1
```